# Paypal IPN always returns INVALID

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am using this listener I downloaded here [Paypal-IPN-listener](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN). The problem is I always get an "INVALID" response. I've checked my host provider and they confirmed that the server has OpenSSL v1.0.1 which supports TLS1.2. Any help would be much appreciated.

The response I get:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 03:32:59 GMT Server: Apache
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Set-Cookie:
>   c9MWDuvPtT9GIMyPc3jwol1VSlO=M5RZRbR9O0p3RyZcCd57VOjVO7vQahSBxti78obb5GWSaRge7FbInlJm9xeF6VIGA8jPMUyenYAZxlLOd4-YqTmucvLu0i7lWMg5RM94Q0SFZOVZ1_ysAo5Y_G3ISqMX_oc5Ts8Xqy5z9q8YKYW-RCBOKKo6ZpkXYUKF2RyjbOQIV3jeUWUSBBtkl4SxeDFi4MUm49opYTa6CvKAqQZ4vr6cWpOQghPpmEsz0s175Z8k6UtTfB99JV14faev1SBZUafmOkyNWCT3XSUF_dRWx-RAQ9L_T8MPetd5beRMm5fXBY1rvehFXw33aUvhTxckwGBJrdrKW2bOQa0Ry6YaRdp1uvdMC6uCuesozTjKXBFgSf0g0cDdHXoxV0rgVPTMlTRoVoV9xNJJ1CNKZzxeCvaFBZNSQdSTT888w0;
>   domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie:
>   cookie_check=yes; expires=Mon, 08-Jun-2026 03:32:59 GMT;
>   domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie:
>   navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
>   Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Sun, 10-Jun-2018 03:32:59 GMT;
>   domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie:
>   Apache=10.72.108.11.1465529579669687; path=/; expires=Sun, 03-Jun-46
>   03:32:59 GMT Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent X-Cnection: close
>   HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR: sandbox.slc Paypal-Debug-Id: 5d6d91989f423
>   Set-Cookie:
>   X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D3946076759%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Dsandbox.slc;
>   Expires=Fri, 10 Jun 2016 04:03:00 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/;
>   Secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970
>   00:00:01 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> INVALID
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- payment_type             instant payment_date             Fri Jun 10
>   2016 11:02:14 GMT 0800 (PHT) payment_status           Completed
>   address_status           confirmed payer_status             verified
>   first_name               John last_name                Smith
>   payer_email              buyer@paypalsandbox.com payer_id
>   TESTBUYERID01 address_name             John Smith address_country
>   United States address_country_code     US address_zip
>   95131 address_state            CA address_city             San Jose
>   address_street           123 any street business
>   seller@paypalsandbox.com receiver_email
>   seller@paypalsandbox.com receiver_id
>   seller@paypalsandbox.com residence_country        US item_name1
>   something item_number1             AK-1234 tax
>   2.02 mc_currency              USD mc_fee                   0.44 mc_gross                 12.34 mc_gross_1               12.34
>   mc_handling              2.06 mc_handling1             1.67
>   mc_shipping              3.02 mc_shipping1             1.02 txn_type
>   cart txn_id                   331854069 notify_version           2.1
>   custom                   xyz123 invoice                  abc1234
>   test_ipn                 1 verify_sign
>   AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AfWDVp14NjdjOS60QpDQiiFYCMSm

**ipn.php:**

```
<?php


include('listener/ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

$listener->use_sandbox = true;

try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $file = fopen("log.txt","w");
    fwrite($file,$e->getMessage());
    fclose($file);
    exit(0);
}


if ($verified) {
    $file = fopen("log.txt","w");
    fwrite($file,$listener->getTextReport());
    fclose($file);

} else {
    $file = fopen("log.txt","w");
    fwrite($file,$listener->getTextReport());
    fclose($file);
}

?>
```

**ipnlistener.php**

```
<?php
/**
 *  PayPal IPN Listener
 *
 *  A class to listen for and handle Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) from 
 *  the PayPal server.
 *
 *  https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *
 *  @package    PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @author     Micah Carrick
 *  @copyright  (c) 2012 - Micah Carrick
 *  @version    2.1.0
 */
class IpnListener {

    /**
     *  If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back 
     *  to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_curl = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, explicitly sets cURL to use SSL version 3. Use this if cURL
     *  is compiled with GnuTLS SSL.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any 
     *  "Location: ..." headers in the response.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $follow_location = false;     

    /**
     *  If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back 
     *  as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
     *  is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_ssl = true;      

    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = true; 

    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
                    dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/cacert.pem");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful. 
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and 
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */    
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST. 
     */    
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code? what triggers "Invalid" ?

Comment: if you are using sandbox to test, have you change the $use_sandbox variable to true? sounds like your listener is posting back to the live site

Comment: @user6439245 yes that property is set to true.

Comment: @Dagon OP updated with codes

Comment: It should be set to true in both ipn.php and ipnlistener.php. If you have already done so, then post the code of your ipn.php and ipnlistener.php files here by editing your question.

Comment: @user6439245 OP updated with ipnlistener.php

Answer (score 1):

Debugging steps

1. Check if the script is pointing to the correct path in both your IPN listener and the output generation script.
   ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr for Sandbox (inc. IPN simulator)
   ssl://www.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr for the live site

Only SSL connection is permitted for Sandbox.
The HTTP protocol can still be used for the live site at the time of writing.

1. Check if you server supports TLS 1.2
   PayPal is updating its services to require TLS v1.2 for all HTTPS/TLS
2. if you use fsockopen()m makes sure the function has been enabled in your PHP configuration
3. if you use curl() functions makes sure, they are enabled in your PHP configuration
4. Check if curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, ) is set to the correct version, i.e. 6 at the time of writing
5. If all the above has been checked and you still can't get it to work, you can trying putting NULL in the payment date field of the IPN simulator, to see if it returns a VERIFIED result.

   The plus sign used for timezone in payment date can cause problem
   when urlencode() is used to parse the URL.

Comment: Nothing changed. **$listener->use_sandbox = true;** should set that property in the object to true. **public $use_sandbox = false;** is just the default.

Comment: you may be looking at the wrong place,  $listener->use_sandbox = true;  is in your ipn.php script, public $use_sandbox = false; is in your ipnlistener.php script

Comment: you need to change the default value in ipnlistener.php from $use_sandbox = false; to $use_sandbox = true; otherwise, it would post to the live site hence the invalid response. See the Paypal developer manual on IPN testing https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/#invalid

Comment: Try changing curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); to  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); for testing purpose
If I remember correctly PayPal have disabled SSLv3 2 years back.

Comment: yes it's already **curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);** as you can see in ipnlistener.php

Comment: can you post a new log entry one that after you have changed $use_sandbox to true

Comment: If you are using the IPN simulator, trying putting NULL in the payment date field, to see if it returns a VERIFIED result.

Comment: @ClydeScope have you tried putting NULL in the payment date field, to see if it returns a VERIFIED result. I tested your code on my server, it works fine if I put NULL in the payment date field, It has to do with the + sign they use in the data timezone format which get messed up when combined with urlencode() when the data is send back. removing the + sign from the text box in IPN field doesn't work (I tried) but typing NULL in the field solves the problem.